# Atiyah-Macdonald #7.24, about going-up property of function

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> 7.24. Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring, $f: A\rightarrow B$ a ring homomorphism of finite type (that is, $B$ is a finitely generated $f(A)$-algebra). Then $f^*$ is an open mapping if and only if $f$ has going-up property.

The following is what I did:

"If" direction is easy.
For the only-if part, the book gives me a hint.

Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec}(B)$. Since we want to show $f^*$ is open mapping, let $V$ be open in $Y$. Then $V$ is union of basic open sets, $X_g$. However, if we denote $B_g$ as a localization of $B$ at $g$, it is clear that $X_g\cong\operatorname{Spec}(B_g)$. Since the composition
$$A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow B_g $$
is again a ring homormorphism of finite type, we are brought down to the situation that $V=Y$.
Thus, our claim is $E:=f^*(Y)$ is open in $X$.

Then here, book makes me stuck :
"The going down property asserts that if $\mathfrak{p} \in E$ and $\mathfrak{p}'\subseteq \mathfrak{p}$, then $\mathfrak{p}'\in E$.

I can't understand why this fact follows from going-down property. If $\mathfrak{p}=f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$ for some prime $\mathfrak{q}$ in B,(this is just rewriting of $\mathfrak{p} \in E$) then since $f(\mathfrak{p}') \subseteq f(\mathfrak{p})$ and $f(\mathfrak{p})=\mathfrak{q} \cap f(A)$, applying the going down property, there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}'$ in B such that $f(\mathfrak{p}\prime)=\mathfrak{q}' \cap f(A)$. But this doesn't implies $\mathfrak{p}' \in E$, since we don't know about whether $f^{-1}(f(\mathfrak{p}'))=\mathfrak{p}'$.

Can anyone help me? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What stick? That's exactly the definition of the going-down property: if  $\mathfrak p=f^{-1}(\mathfrak q)$ and if $\mathfrak p\supset\mathfrak p'$, there exists $\mathfrak q'\in\operatorname{Spec}B$ such that $\mathfrak q'\subset \mathfrak q$ and $f^{-1}(\mathfrak q')=\mathfrak p'$.

Comment: Why that's a definition? Following your notation, Atiyah says there exists $\mathfrak{q}' \in$ Spec $B$ such that $\mathfrak{q}' \subseteq \mathfrak{q}$ and " $f(\mathfrak{p}')=\mathfrak{q}' \cap f(A)$.

Comment: I think definition would be modified as you tell me.

Comment: That' this property, established for flat morphisms in particular (2nd theorem of Cohen-Seidenberg) that is call the going-down property.

Comment: I have the feeling you confuse $f:A\longrightarrow B\:$ and $f^*:\operatorname{Spec}B\longrightarrow\operatorname{Spec}A $.